# How to denoise an image using least square and regularization?

Tags: python, image, least-squares

**f = u+n: f is noisy image, u is an desired reconstruction and n is noise.**

**The reconstruction error is ||u-f||_2^2 + lambda * ||gradient(u)||_2^2**

**Solve ||Ax-b||_2^2 where x is a vector that is vectorised from f in column-wise.**

the above is my problem and I can't understand what means "solve ||Ax-b||_2^2".
what is 'A'? what is 'b'? How can get 'the reconstruction'?

I know the simple way of find minimizing least square using pseudo inverse. 
But I just adjusted the way on find θ in ||Aθ-b||^2.

I don't know what I have to do. So I did what can I do.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal 
from skimage import io, color
from skimage import exposure

file_image  = 'image.jpg'

im_color    = io.imread(file_image)
im_gray     = color.rgb2gray(im_color)
im          = (im_gray - np.mean(im_gray)) / np.std(im_gray)
(row, col)  = im.shape

noise_std   = 0.2 # try with varying noise standard deviation
noise       = np.random.normal(0, noise_std, (row, col))
im_noise    = im + noise
```

I made a noisy image. and I don't know next step.

Is there anyone who can explain?

Comment: Please edit the question, as you can see there is no problem description.

Answer (score 1):

This very much looks like a poorly phrased homework question. I have a fair background in mathematical image processing and inverse problems so I rewrote it for you the only way it makes sense.

> Let *f* be a noisy image described by the relationship *f = u+n*,
>   where *u* is a noise-free image and *n* is the noise. The goal is to
>   recover *u* from *n*. To do this, we introduce the following function
>
> *||u - f||²*,
>
> which is equal to the squared summed difference between all pixels in
>   *u* and *f*, to measure the similarity between *u* and *f*. Furthermore, we introduce the following function to measure the amount
>   of noise in the image
>
> *||Du||²*,
>
> where *Du(x, y)* represents the magnitude of the gradient of *u* at
>   position *(x, y)*, as a measure of the noise in an image. By
>   *||Du||²*, we therefore mean the squared sum of the gradient in all pixels.
>
> A way to measure how well we have reconstructed the noise-free image can then be represented by the following function
>
> *||u - f||² + ||Du||²*
>
> Solve the regularised least squares problem above.